# Permissions issue with a canvas app

Tags: canvas

I was having the same issues as discussed in this question:

[Error rendering Force.com Canvas application](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22626/error-rendering-force-com-canvas-application)

and was able to get the app working by setting the app to use "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" and then adding a profile to the "Profiles" of the installed app.  This works and allows my app to render, but if possible I would like to be able to use "All users may self-authorize" setting so I don't require the extra step of setting the profiles on the app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible today if you use OAuth Web Flow as your Access Method in your canvas app.  If you wish to use Signed Request, you will have to use Admin Approved Users only.

We are looking to add this capability soon, so check back over the next couple of releases.